# Using Rvest to extract data from webpage keep getting NA, "", or {xml_nodeset (0)}

Tags: r, rvest

i'm trying to use Rvest to extract the actual and projected medals from this page

https://projects.fivethirtyeight.com/olympics-medal-count/

but for some reason can't get any text from it.

I've been trying multiple variations of

```
page<-read_html("https://projects.fivethirtyeight.com/olympics-medal-count/")

page %>% 
  html_nodes('.countries')%>%
  html_nodes('.actual-rank') %>%
  html_text()

page %>% 
  html_nodes('.actual-rank') %>%
  html_text()

page %>% 
  html_nodes('div.rank-value') %>%
  html_text()
```

But never am getting anything other than some variation of blank/missing data.

Any help or direction would be really appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: The data is not in the source of the page, it's loaded via javascript after page load. `rvest` cannot execute javascript so you cannot use it to scrape that page.

Comment: Ah, right thanks. Any recommendations for how to go about getting it from java? Also if you want to put this as an answer happy to mark it as it.

Comment: It appear most of the data is stored as a JSON file here: https://projects.fivethirtyeight.com/olympics-medal-count/data.json